# Does robotFramework-appium supports Python3+?

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, appium, robotframework

I heard that robotFramework-appium is not actively maintained. So is it better to go for java appium?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about robotframework-appium but `robotframework-appiumlibrary` is actively maintained.

[Github Page for robotframework-appiumlibrary:](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary)

Also for python3 support; there has been updates and releases, it is mostly good now. There is another version under development for full support.